# How to create a log4j.xml file for the dynamic web project?

Tags: java, xml, logging

Actually I am trying to implement log4j.file for my dynamic web project.
Here is my `web.xml`

Here I have given `web.xml` code for only log file

**web.xml**

```
<!-- Log File-->

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.ss.logFile.startupListener.StartupListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout, rollingFile
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n
log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=WEB-INF/logs/application.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=512KB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n
log4j.appender.rollingFile.Encoding=UTF-8
```

**StartupListener**

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
@WebServlet("/StartupListener")
public class StartupListener extends HttpServlet implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {    
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        java.util.logging.Logger logger = null;
        String log4jFile = sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter("log4jFileName");
        DOMConfigurator.configure(sce.getServletContext().getRealPath(log4jFile));
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(StartupListener.class.getName());
        logger.debug("Loaded: " + log4jFile);   
    }
}
```

***Sir Actually I am very new to log4j, so that i don't how to write log4j.xml file and where to place that file exaclty.Kindly help me to solve this issue.Thanks in advance***

Comment: I'm not sure if Log4jConfigListener is necessary at all. If you put the configuration file at /WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties, log4j should pick up the file automatically

Comment: I need the steps to create a log4j.xml file and I have to set the path for the log file where it should go and store the data.

Comment: Use this link http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-log4j-integration-example/ this link will give u a complete information of using log4j

Answer (score 0):

According to the config you posted. You are not using xml but properties file. As Adam Dyga had said as long as the log4j.properties file is in the classpath, it will be picked up by the application automatically. You do not need to load explicitly. To set the location of the log file,

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile.file=D:/MyWEBLogs/MyWEB.log
```